# What is the loss function of the Mask RCNN?

Tags: deep-learning, object-detection

The paper has clearly mentioned the **classification and regression** losses are identical to the RPN network in the Faster RCNN . Can someone explain the Mask Loss function . How the use FCN to improve ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

FCN uses per-pixel softmax and a multinominal loss. This means, that the mask prediction task (the boundaries of the object) and the class prediction task (what is the object being masked) are coupled.
Mask-RCNN decouples these tasks: the existing bounding-box prediction (AKA the localization task) head predicts the class, like faster-RCNN, and the mask branch generates a mask **for each class**, without competition among classes (e.g. if you have 21 classes the mask branch predicts 21 masks instead of FCN's single mask with 21 channels). The loss being used is per-pixel sigmoid + binary loss.
Bottom line, it's Sigmoid in Mask-RCNN vs. Soft-max in FCN.
([See table 2.b. in Mask RCNN paper - Ablation section](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1703.06870.pdf)).

Comment: I am a bit confused. In Mask R-CNN there are 5 Losses. RPN Class and BBox and Mask Class, BBox and Mask Loss. In Fast R-CNN the RPN the first output was a probability distribution over K+1 categories. The second output was the bounding box regression. Is it correct that in Mask R-CNN the RPN only has two categories as opposed to Fast R-CNN: object or not object? And the Mask-Head has three losses and here the Loss from Mask_BBox is the same as RPN_BBox and the Loss from Mask_Class is the same as RPN_class, but as opposed to RPN for all K categories?

Comment: You said, 21 claess predicts 21 masks, then inside one class how to distinguish instances, I mean, if one mask have a class all instances, how to divide them out?

Answer (score 6):

The multi-task loss function of Mask R-CNN combines the loss of classification, localization and segmentation mask: L=Lcls+Lbox+Lmask, 
where Lcls and Lbox are same as in Faster R-CNN.

The mask branch generates a mask of dimension m x m for each RoI and each class; K classes in total. Thus, the total output is of size K⋅m^2

Because the model is trying to learn a mask for each class, there is no competition among classes for generating masks.

Lmask :

is defined as the average binary cross-entropy loss, only including k-th mask if the region is associated with the ground truth class k.
[image: Lmask Equation]

where yij
is the label of a cell (i, j) in the true mask for the region of size m x m; y^kij is the predicted value of the same cell in the mask learned for the ground-truth class k.